# orchard in a shared hosting with medium trust

Tags: security, hosting, orchardcms, medium-trust

I've installed our Orchard 1.2.41 based website on a shared hosting with medium trust.

The site won't work, complaining with the infamous error:

`Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.`

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I've tried to add

`< trust level="Full" originUrl="" />`

but to no avail. The web server tells me that the web.config is invalid. Probably the medium trust is locked by the hoster.

I've read on the web that orchard is written to work on medium trust environments, only with a performance loss. For now, I just want to get my company site up and running.

any clue?
thank you, grazie.
m.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latest versions do not support medium trust (and won't do). Medium trust break lots of things, makes the code much harder to maintain/develop and is a pain in general.

Your best bet would be to change your current hoster. If they don't give you full trust, you should run away from there asap - all major hosters do that now. It's the only futureproof solution. Otherwise you'll constantly run into some issues.

Comment: I'll add that medium trust is completely useless. Microsoft officially recommends not using it. +1 on running away from any hoster that does medium trust in 2013.

Comment: Also, Orchard 1.2 is very old. You should be using 1.6.

Comment: I've managed to get my hosting company to let us use full trust. thanks a lot to everyone.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Do you have a link to that Microsoft recommendation of not using medium trust?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-45/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet,-and-what-to-do-instead#medium

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2698981